# ng repeat when array index is changed ie array['1234']

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Trying to implement a simple ng-repeat with array having index changed according to my requirements

```
 $scope.arr["123"] = { id: '123', name: 'ali', speed: '0' }
 &&
 $scope.arr["345"] = { id: '345', name: 'umar', speed: '1' }
 and so on...
```

Now as length of array in 0 ng-repeat is not helpfull need to know the alternative as my .ejs file code:

```
               <div ng-repeat="items in arr">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 item two">
                        <div class="full-width-float multiviewbox-inner">
                            <div class="multiuser-status-up">
                                <span class="cn_item multi-cross">
                                   <i class="cross-toogle-black"></i>
                               </span>
                                <div class="float-left-left">
                                    <span class="badge user-act-mul"> 
                              {{items.name}}</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="multiuser-status-down">
                                <div class="float-left-left">
                                    <span class="cn_item badge">
                                   <i class="sprite-weeklyicon iconweekly- 
                             2"></i>
                                  <span class="speed-multi-user">Speed <span 
                             class="text-primary">{{items.speed}} 
                              </span>kmph</span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="float-right-right multimap- 
                                 fullscreen-on">
                                    <span class="cn_item badge">
                                   <i class="multimap-fullscreen"></i>
                               </span>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: `$scope.arr` is not an array, it's an object. You need to use `ng-repeat="(key, items) in arr"`

Comment: i tried ng-repeat="(key, items) in arr" but it was not working

Comment: define "not working".

Comment: ng-repeat with (key,items) didnot get any data same as simple ng-repeat

Comment: @briosheje the referenced example http://next.plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview  uses // $scope.data = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2" };  // if you convert it into //$scope.data['id1'] = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val1" };
  $scope.data['id2'] = { prop1: "val2", prop2: "val2" };//  then it did not work

Comment: @saad it does work, it just logs the json, you need to work with key-value pairs accordingly: `<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in data">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
          Prop1: {{val.prop1}} <br />
          Prop2: {{val.prop2}}
        </td>
      </tr>`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc plz remove the comment as my question is change! thanks

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman did you check the duplicate link? it answer exactly your question.

Comment: yes i did and already told you its not the same

Comment: Can you show the `console.log($scope.arr)`?

Comment: Array(346)
123: {id: "123", name: "ali", speed: "0"}
345: {id: "345", name: "umar", speed: "1"}
length: 346
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're trying to iterate over an array while `arr` is an object. If you are still getting an error, you're probably not initializing `arr`.

Here is a working example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
    $scope.arr = {};
    $scope.arr["123"] = {
      id: '123',
      name: 'ali',
      speed: '0'
    };

    $scope.arr["345"] = {
      id: '345',
      name: 'umar',
      speed: '1'
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, items) in arr">
    <div class="col-sm-6 item two">
      <div class="full-width-float multiviewbox-inner">
        <div class="multiuser-status-up">
          <span class="cn_item multi-cross">
             <i class="cross-toogle-black"></i>
           </span>
          <div class="float-left-left">
            <span class="badge user-act-mul"> 
              {{items.name}}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="multiuser-status-down">
          <div class="float-left-left">
            <span class="cn_item badge">
              <i class="sprite-weeklyicon iconweekly-2"></i>
            <span class="speed-multi-user">
              Speed
              <span class="text-primary">{{items.speed}} 
              </span>kmph</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="float-right-right multimap-fullscreen-on">
            <span class="cn_item badge">
              <i class="multimap-fullscreen"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```